# Ruby code to check if a website has search engine friendly URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, friendly-url, seo

I am developing an application in rails which requires to check whether the entered website has search engine friendly URLs generated or not.A solution i have in mind is using nokogiri to parse the HTML of the site and look in the link tag for finding URLs and see if they are search engine friendly.Is there any other way this can be done?Any help would be really great.

Comment: if you really want to look at all links in the page, nokogiri is the way to go. how do you plan on distinguishing a SEO-friendly url from a non-SEO-friendly one?

Comment: I haven't any idea about how i would do that.I'll look into Anemone first as @Casper has suggested.Do you have other way that could work for this case?Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately not, i was just being curious ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. How do you formally (programmatically) define what a "search engine frienldy URL is". I'm assuming you have some way of doing this already. So that leaves...
2. How to check all the links on a website.

So for (2) I would look at something like [Anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/) which will make it easy for you to crawl complete websites:

> Anemone is a Ruby library that makes it quick and painless to write programs that spider a website. It provides a simple DSL for performing actions on every page of a site, skipping certain URLs, and calculating the shortest path to a given page on a site.
>
> The multi-threaded design makes Anemone fast. The API makes it simple. And the expressiveness of Ruby makes it powerful.

For simple crawling Anemone will even give you an array of all links on a page, so you won't necessarily even need Nokogiri. For more complex stuff maybe you want to combine Anemone with something like [Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) and Nokogiri. That depends on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for sharing information about the Anemone Gem, it would be very useful to me.I also haven't really figured out a way to the (1) problem, So if you have help about that then please share that too.

Comment: @JimmyThakkar - Thanks for your comments. Unfortunately no I don't have any good ideas for the SEO links. It's not an easy problem to solve. What I would do is first write down on paper what a good SEO link is. I.e. create a definition on paper first! After that you could try and formulate an algorithm for it. But first you need to have the rules clear. Maybe look for matching keywords on the page etc.. However humans can pretty quickly see if a link is SEO or not. So just implementing (2) you can already list the links and quickly scan 100+ links in just a few seconds by just looking at them.

Comment: @JimmyThakkar Were you able to come up with a solution for the (1) problem ?